# Expanding denominator in a power series, mismatch of the expansion

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion, power-series

Below is a snippet from the book [Ralston:First course in numerical analysis](http://library.lol/main/0F9244B182926B419E73DBBA1D249950) but it seems to me that something is wrong with $(10.2-11):$ the denominator divided by $a_1\lambda_1^m$ starts with $1$ not with $\lambda_1$. Anyway, I cannot expand and obtain $\lambda_1+\beta_i(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^m+[\text{terms in }(\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1})^m,...,(\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1})^m \text{ and higher powers}].$

Moreover it seems to me that $(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^m$ is of the **same order** as
$(\frac{\lambda_3}{\lambda_1})^m,...$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series expansion is sound. We obtain
\begin{align*}
&\frac{a_1\lambda_1^{m+1}+\sum_{j=2}^{n}a_j\lambda_j^{m+1}}{a_1\lambda_1^m+\sum_{j=2}^na_j\lambda_j^m}
=\frac{a_1\lambda_1^{m}\left(\lambda_1^{m}+\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{a_j\lambda_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^{m}\right)}{a_1\lambda_1^m\left(1+\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{a_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^m\right)}\\
&\quad=\frac{\lambda_1^{m}+\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{a_j\lambda_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^{m}}{1+\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{a_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^m}\\
&\quad=\left(\color{blue}{\lambda_1^{m}+\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{a_j\lambda_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^{m}}\right)\\
&\quad\quad\quad\cdot\left(\color{blue}{1} - \left(\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{a_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^m\right)+
\left(\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{a_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^m\right)^2-\cdots\right)\tag{1}\\
&\quad=\lambda_1^{m}+\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{a_j\lambda_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^{m}+
\mathrm{terms\ of\ higher\ order}\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
We see in (1) $\beta_i:=\frac{a_2\lambda_2}{a_1}$ the factor in the sum with $j=2$. The author considers also all terms of the sum $\sum_{j=2}^n\frac{a_j}{a_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^m$ to be of the same order.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we make a geometric series expansion $\frac{1}{1+z}=1-z+z^2-z^3+\cdots$.
- In (2) we see the explicitly stated terms are derived from the multiplication of the blue terms in the line above. Multiplication with other terms which are not marked as blue produce higher order terms.

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer. You really mean "as blue produce **lower order** terms", right ?

Comment: @user122424: You're welcome and yes, that's what I mean.